# Returning System.Action from static method on generic type with types defined at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

Below is a very paired down example of what I am trying to achieve

```
public class CoolClass<T>
{
    public static void DoSomethingCool()
    {
        // Insert cool generic stuff here.
        List<T> coolList = new List<T>();
    }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public Action ReturnActionBasedOnStaticGenericMethodForType(Type type)
    {
        // Ideally this would just be
        return CoolClass<type **insert magic**>.DoSomethingCool
    }
}
```

I know if the type is known I can do following and it will return System.Action

```
return CoolClass<string>.DoSomethingCool
```

I know if all I wanted to do was invoke the method I can do

```
Type baseType = typeof(CoolClass<>);
Type[] typeArguments = new [] {type}
Type constructedType = baseType.MakeGenericType(typeArguments);
MethodInfo method = constructedType.GetMethod("DoSomethingCool");
method.Invoke(null,null);
```

I maybe down the wrong path all together. It seems like I am trying go get `method` to be a reference to `DoSomethingCool` method. I am wishing for something like `(Action) method`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're nearly there - you just need [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx):

```
Action action = (Action) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(action), null, method);
```

Comment: Ahh, so close. I did realize that if I created another static method called GetDoSomethingCool, for example, that returned the DoSomethingCool that would also work. Your solution is more elegant.